# What are the pros and cons of LinkedHashMaps vs. LinkedHashSets?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap, linkedhashset

Could someone explain the main benefits for choosing one over the other and the detriments that come with that choice?

Comment: I got confused and asked a stupid question, thanks for the quick answers though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They solve different problems, LinkedHashMap does a mapping of keys to values, a LinkedHashSet simply stores a collection of things with no duplicates.

A linked hash map is for mapping key/value pairs -- for example, storing names and ages:

```
Map<String,Integer> namesAndAges = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
namesAndAges.put("Benson", 25);
namesAndAges.put("Fred", 19);
```

On the other hand, a linked hash set is for storing a collection of one thing -- names, for example:

```
Set<String> names = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
names.add("Benson");
names.add("Fred");
```

Comment: I was just looking the source code of the ArrayList just to make sure that I had to use a Set (which has good search performance) instead of an ArrayList (which has to traverse all the records to find something)

Comment: The purpose of LinkedHashMap over HashMap is that LinkedHashMap also uses a LinkedList internally to store the order the key/value pairs have been added. So iterating over the LinkedHashMap will result in key/value pair in the order they were added while a classic HashMap will iterate based on the order of the hashcode of each key.

Comment: That's correct, but since the question was comparing LinkedHashMaps to LinkedHashSets I decided to focus on the differences, rather than the commonalities. :-)

Comment: Fine with me Benson, that's why I'm only adding a comment. I just thought the author was not that experienced with Java and wanted to add some more information :)

Answer (score 6):

LinkedHashSet internally contain a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries that defines the order of elements.
This class permits null elements.

**This class implementation is not synchronized, so it must be synchronized externally.**
**LinkedHashMap is not synchronized either and must be synchronized externally**

For example:

```
Map map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap());
```

Other than that LinkedHashSet stores single values per element and LinkedHashMap stores key/value pair.
In the diagram below you can see java.util.Collections. Solid boxes show concrete class implementation
[alt text http://www.softfinity.com/diag1.png](http://www.softfinity.com/diag1.png)

Answer (score 3):

A Set has just values, you cannot put duplicates in.  a Map has a key/value pair.  They have different uses.

A set will get used as a collection, passing in a group of objects, whereas a map is useful for when you have a unique key to identify each element and you want to be able to access it by that key.

Answer (score 2):

One's a set, and one's a map. Choose the correct data structure for a given scenario.

Answer (score 2):

`LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet` has only one difference and that comes by `HashMap` and `HashSet` difference, their parents. Again, `HashSet` is just a variation of `HashMap`. You can say `HashSet` as a `HashMap` with all values pointing to a single final object. Therefore, both of them does not give you much differences.

Using `LinkedHashSet`, You shall be using only one final object other than your keys.
Using `LinkedHashMap`, if you set values as null for all keys, then its better than LinkedHashSet for Set purpose as well.